# Searching a filtered dataframe for a specific string and then creating a new column based on the results (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter my dataframe (hospital) for situations where the "brain bleeding" column is True. I then want to search the brain_info column for a particular word ("cancer) and then create a new column that has that word ("cancer").

I have done this before in situations without the filtering component, but I am having trouble with this scenario.

```
#What I have

| brain bleeding| brain info  |                                 |final diagnosis|
|---------------|-------------|                                 ----------------
| True          | BlahBlahBlah|       I want to add this column |               |
| True          | Cancer      |                                 |Cancer         |
| False         | Cancer      |                                 |               |


#Creating an empty column in my dataframe for the final diagnosis.
hospital["final_diagnosis"] = ""

#Filter cases where brain cancer is True
filt = (hospital["brain_bleeding"] == True)

#Search for the filtered cases if the diagnosis contains "cancer" and adds it to the corresponding "final_diagnosis" cell, if it is there. This is where my error is?
hospital.loc[filt, 'brain_info'].str.contains("cancer", case=False, na=False), "final diagnosis"] = "cancer"
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is:

```
brain_bleeding  brain_info
True            BlahBlahBlah
True            Cancer
False           Cancer
```

You can try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

hospital = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\t')

# add True to final_diagnosis column if brain is bleeding and brain info is cancer
hospital.loc[(hospital['brain_bleeding'] == True) & 
             (hospital['brain_info'] == 'Cancer'), 'final_diagnosis'] = True
hospital['final_diagnosis'].fillna('', inplace=True) # replace NaN with empty strings

print(hospital)
```

Output:

```
   brain_bleeding    brain_info final_diagnosis
0            True  BlahBlahBlah                
1            True        Cancer            True
2           False        Cancer
```

Note: I've added two conditions based on `final_diagnosis` column from your example - it looks like you possibly want just one condition though (feed free two remove one one 'em if needed).